# ElasticSearch crash after updating/create doc

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem when I want to update my database with around 80 000 products with 11 fields, ES crashed. I use symfony and I have a subscriber to update the ES database each time a product is updated or created.

But when I'm updating all the database at one moment I have that error :

```
[2021-10-12T02:11:22,931][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@2e1c6a7d, interval=5s}] took [30256ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:12:19,821][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@2e1c6a7d, interval=5s}] took [48557ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:12:34,931][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [org.elasticsearch.cluster.InternalClusterInfoService$RefreshScheduler$$Lambda$5704/0x00000008018c6db8@78185ebe] took [6292ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:13:46,250][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@2e1c6a7d, interval=5s}] took [69667ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:14:04,113][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [org.elasticsearch.cluster.InternalClusterInfoService$RefreshScheduler$$Lambda$5704/0x00000008018c6db8@7f02cfbb] took [7152ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:15:21,661][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@2e1c6a7d, interval=5s}] took [76026ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:15:43,542][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [org.elasticsearch.cluster.InternalClusterInfoService$RefreshScheduler$$Lambda$5704/0x00000008018c6db8@3600a0f1] took [7618ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:17:26,994][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@2e1c6a7d, interval=5s}] took [100731ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:17:43,165][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [org.elasticsearch.cluster.InternalClusterInfoService$RefreshScheduler$$Lambda$5704/0x00000008018c6db8@31403959] took [5589ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:18:41,718][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@2e1c6a7d, interval=5s}] took [57778ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:18:57,466][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [org.elasticsearch.cluster.InternalClusterInfoService$RefreshScheduler$$Lambda$5704/0x00000008018c6db8@5b704f64] took [6443ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:20:00,132][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@2e1c6a7d, interval=5s}] took [61752ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:20:19,545][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [org.elasticsearch.cluster.InternalClusterInfoService$RefreshScheduler$$Lambda$5704/0x00000008018c6db8@58d5ebe1] took [6910ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:21:44,007][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@2e1c6a7d, interval=5s}] took [83065ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:22:52,863][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@2e1c6a7d, interval=5s}] took [60421ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:23:02,766][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.monitor.jvm.JvmGcMonitorService$1@b97d247, interval=1s}] took [6754ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:23:35,325][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [org.elasticsearch.cluster.InternalClusterInfoService$RefreshScheduler$$Lambda$5704/0x00000008018c6db8@706bd30d] took [14295ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:23:47,068][WARN ][o.e.m.f.FsHealthService  ] [new-host-name] health check of [/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] took [5288ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5s]
[2021-10-12T02:26:33,254][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@2e1c6a7d, interval=5s}] took [172616ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:26:47,312][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.monitor.jvm.JvmGcMonitorService$1@b97d247, interval=1s}] took [7565ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:27:28,363][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [org.elasticsearch.cluster.InternalClusterInfoService$RefreshScheduler$$Lambda$5704/0x00000008018c6db8@77ba4c1] took [17452ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T02:27:46,940][WARN ][o.e.m.f.FsHealthService  ] [new-host-name] health check of [/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0] took [10560ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5s]
[2021-10-12T02:30:55,163][WARN ][o.e.t.ThreadPool         ] [new-host-name] execution of [ReschedulingRunnable{runnable=org.elasticsearch.watcher.ResourceWatcherService$ResourceMonitor@2e1c6a7d, interval=5s}] took [198915ms] which is above the warn threshold of [5000ms]
[2021-10-12T09:21:03,323][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [new-host-name] version[7.15.0], pid[2069072], build[default/deb/79d65f6e357953a5b3cbcc5e2c7c21073d89aa29/2021-09-16T03:05:29.143308416Z], OS[Linux/5.4.0-88-generic/amd64], JVM[Eclipse Foundation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/16.0.2/16.0.2+7]
[2021-10-12T09:21:03,339][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [new-host-name] JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk], using bundled JDK [true]
[2021-10-12T09:21:03,339][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [new-host-name] JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, -Xms2g, -Xmx2g, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-4446609679435738103, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch, -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1073741824, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=deb, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]
```

My settings for the index :

```
$product_param = [
    'index' => $this->indexName,
    'body' => [
        'settings' => [
            'number_of_shards' => 2,
            'number_of_replicas' => 2,
            'analysis' => [
                'char_filter' => [
                    'pre_negs' => [
                        'type' => 'pattern_replace',
                        'pattern' => 'a \w',
                        'replacement' => ''
                    ],
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    'autocomplete_filter' => [
                        'type' => 'edge_ngram',
                        'min_gram' => '1',
                        'max_gram' => '20',
                    ]
                ],
                "analyzer" => [
                    "autocomplete" => [
                        "filter" => [
                            "lowercase",
                            "autocomplete_filter"
                        ],
                        "type" => "custom",
                        "tokenizer" => "standard",
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'mappings' => [
            'properties' => [
                'pickRef' => [
                    'type' => 'keyword',
                    'boost' => 5
                ],
                'name' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'boost' => 3,
                    'fields' => [
                        "keyword" => [
                            "type" => "keyword",
                            "ignore_above" => 256
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'brand' => [
                    'type' => 'keyword',
                    'boost' => 3
                ],
                'description' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                ],
                'catalogue' => [
                    'type' => 'keyword',
                ],
                'category' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'analyzer' => 'standard'
                ],
                'slug' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                ],
                'image' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                ],
                'enabled' => [
                    'type' => 'boolean',
                ],
                'replaced' => [
                    'type' => 'boolean',
                ],
                'synonym' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'store' => 'false',
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

My Ram is around 2Gb. I thought that only 80 000 products with only 11 fields will not take so much resources.

How can I avoid this error and so, ES to crashed ?

Comment: I think you have on server? why you set replica to 2? and also shard 2? set replica to 0 .

Comment: I will have only one server. I put replica to 2 and shard to 2.. for no real reason (I search in Internet). What do you think about shard ?

Comment: also if you can set shard to 1.

Comment: you have 2 Gb ram. what is heap config? also share _cat/nodes and _cat/thread_pool when elasticsearch crash

Comment: my heap is 2Gb. ES is in my computer and i Can't give more. It's really difficult to me to crash ES. happen randomly from 6h to +  computation. I will try to do that tonight. and see tomorow if I have a crash.

Comment: Did you find a resolution? I'm seeing something similar on a very specific system (can't replicate on a replica system)